# Javascript code works in asp.net but not when called as a function from a file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Ok I have this script for d3.js that I pulled from the net.

```
function draw() {

    var w = 600,
        h = 400,
        z = d3.scale.category20b(),
        i = 0;

    var svg = d3.select("div.container2").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .on("mousemove", particle);
}

function particle() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);

    svg.append("svg:rect")
        .attr("x", m[0] - 10)
        .attr("y", m[1] - 10)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("rx", 10)
        .attr("ry", 10)
        .style("stroke", z(++i))
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
        .style("opacity", 0.7)
      .transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .ease(Math.sqrt)
        .attr("x", m[0] - 100)
        .attr("y", m[1] - 100)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .attr("width", 200)
        .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
        .style("opacity", 1e-6)
        .remove();
}

The part of the asp.net that called the function is simply
<script src="js/d3Script.js"></script>        
    <script>        
        draw();
    </script>
```

Now when I replace the draw function with the Java directly into the ASP page it works fine.  When I call it from the js file it draws the canvas but nothing happens.

The particle function IS called (I checked with an alert) but nothing is drawn.  All the other js files required are in place.

Am I missing something simple??  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply Call Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function draw() {

        var w = 600,
            h = 400,
            z = d3.scale.category20b(),
            i = 0;

        var svg = d3.select("div.container2").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .on("mousemove", particle);
    }
   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function particle() {
        var m = d3.mouse(this);

        svg.append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", m[0] - 10)
            .attr("y", m[1] - 10)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("rx", 10)
            .attr("ry", 10)
            .style("stroke", z(++i))
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
            .style("opacity", 0.7)
          .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .ease(Math.sqrt)
            .attr("x", m[0] - 100)
            .attr("y", m[1] - 100)
            .attr("height", 200)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1e-6)
            .style("opacity", 1e-6)
            .remove();
    }
</script>
```

and function `draw()` and `particle()` call your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I want to be able to use the across multiple pages and post it various data. Wouldn't it be better as a separate file that gets reused? Much appreciated!!!!